# In visual studio, how to automatically input the latter half part of an object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

For example, `Person p = new Person();`
I have to type the letter one by one, or select the word one by one (by intellisense), but I know someone can make the `new Person()` automatically come after they input `Person p`, how to do it?

PS, the intellisense is on in my computer. Sorry for the previous description, i can select "new" or "Person" by intellisense, but system doesnot show "new Person()" together. What I am curious is, after someone type "Person p" or "Person p =",  this "new Person();" can automatically come

Comment: Perhaps you have disabled IntelliSense?

Comment: possibly you mean [`Code snippets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx)

Comment: I can do it by hitting Tab once or twice. However note that the popular Resharper plug-in extends the built-in IntelliSense functionality of Visual Studio a lot. So the "someone" you mentioned could possibly be using Resharper.

Comment: @chiccodoro do you installed Resharper? After I type "Person p =", and then hit TAB, nothing get, just move cursor

Comment: @user3339999 - tab only works once the context menu with intellisense options is open. If that does not happen - as already mentioned by Codor - you probably have IntelliSense disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you mean is probably "intellisense". By default you should be able to hit Ctrl + Space after typing the first letters of a command or variable name to open a dropdownmenu with possible matches. Select the correct entry and continue by pressing "Tab".

Comment: @derape: `Tab` is the better option since it works with C# and also VB.NET whereas `Return` will break the line with VB. If you need to switch between different languages it's better to remember shortcuts that work always.

Comment: Oh did not know that, havent touched VB yet